# Synonym reversal for recovery mode tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I propose we reverse the direction of the tag synonym for recover mode:

[image]

With 25 questions, there doesn't seem to be a need to differentiate between macOS and iOS at this point.

Comment: Aren't both `recovery-mode` and `ios-recovery-mode` for iOS (although there are macOS questions with this tag)?  There is the similar `recovery` tag for macOS which says "*An OS X feature that hides a Recovery HD on Macs to facilitate maintenance, recovery and reinstallation if the OS becomes corrupt.*"